# php and mysql allowing successful login for emails with _ and other special characters

Tags: php, mysql

hi can someone please help me. i have a login script and when i set a users username to `eric@email.com` it works fine but if their email is `eric_1@email.com` and other special characters it echoes out the count error 1 where it says there was one error in the form.

how can i allow my script to succesfully log in user with `_` in their email or with any other special characters? im really new to php and mysql and would really be greatful if someone could show me how to fix this.

```
<?php

    if (logged_in()) 
{ 
$_SESSION['login_message']="<div class=\"login-overlay\"></div><div class=\"login-box\"><div class=\"loginframe2\">
<h1>Login You In Securely </h1>
<p> PlaytimeBoys.com is login you in securely. Please wait.<br/><br/>
<div class=\"login-logo\">
  <img src=\"assets/css/photobox/loading.gif\" width=\"24\" height=\"24\"><div class=\"login-text-logo\">Login You In. Please Wait</div></div>
</div></div>"; 
header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}");

}

    include_once("includes/form_functions.php");

    // START FORM PROCESSING
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { // Form has been submitted.
        $errors = array();

        // perform validations on the form data
        $required_fields = array('email', 'password');
        $errors = array_merge($errors, check_required_fields($required_fields, $_POST));

        $fields_with_lengths = array('email' => 30, 'password' => 30);
        $errors = array_merge($errors, check_max_field_lengths($fields_with_lengths, $_POST));

        $email = trim(mysql_prep($_POST['email']));
        $password = trim(mysql_prep($_POST['password']));
        $hashed_password = md5($password);


        if ( empty($errors) ) {
            // Check database to see if email and the hashed password exist there.
            $query = "SELECT id, email, close_account ";
            $query .= "FROM ptb_users ";
            $query .= "WHERE email = '{$email}' ";
            $query .= "AND password = '{$hashed_password}' ";
            $query .= "AND close_account = '0' ";
            $query .= "LIMIT 1";
            $result_set = mysql_query($query);
            confirm_query($result_set);
            if (mysql_num_rows($result_set) == 1) {
                // email/password authenticated
                // and only 1 match
                $found_user = mysql_fetch_array($result_set);
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $found_user['id'];
                $_SESSION['email'] = $found_user['email'];
                $_SESSION['sub_expires'] = $found_user['subscription_expires'];





                $result = mysql_query("UPDATE ptb_users SET user_online='Online' WHERE id=".$_SESSION['user_id']."") 
or die(mysql_error());

if($result) 
{ 
$_SESSION['login_message']="<div class=\"login-overlay\"></div><div class=\"login-box\"><div class=\"loginframe2\">
<h1>Login You In Securely </h1>
<p>login you in securely. Please wait.<br/><br/>
<div class=\"login-logo\">
  <img src=\"assets/css/photobox/loading.gif\" width=\"24\" height=\"24\"><div class=\"login-text-logo\">Login You In. Please Wait</div></div>
</div></div>"; 
header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}");

}


            }else{

                // email/password combo was not found in the database
                $message = "<div class=\"infobox_out\"><strong>Email / Password combination incorrect.</strong><br />
                    Please make sure your caps lock key is off and try again.</div>";
                    echo "<a href=\"#\"><div class=\"infobox-close2\"></div></a>";

            }

                } else {
            if (count($errors) == 1) {
                $message = "<div class=\"infobox_out\">There was 1 error in the form.<div>";


            } else {
                $message = "<div class=\"infobox_out\">There were " . count($errors) . " errors in the form.<div>";
            }
        }


    } else { // Form has not been submitted.
        if (isset($_GET['logout']) && $_GET['logout'] == 1) {
            $message = "<div class=\"infobox\">You are now logged out.</div>";
            echo "<a href=\"#\"><div class=\"infobox-close3\"></div></a>";

            } else { // Form has not been submitted.
        if (isset($_GET['logout']) && $_GET['logout'] == 5) {
            $message = "<div class=\"infobox-noprofile2\"><strong>Account Banned -</strong> We could not log you in because your account's<br/> been banned. Contact us at: <a href=\"mailto:Support@PlaytimeBoys.com\">Support@admin.com</a>.</div>";
            echo "<a href=\"#\"><div class=\"infobox-close12\"></div></a>";

            } else { // Form has not been submitted.
        if (isset($_GET['logout']) && $_GET['logout'] == 6) {
            $message = "<div class=\"infobox-noprofile2\"><strong>Account Warning -</strong> You recently violated a condition in our User Policy. Due to this you are receiving this warning. If you continue to violate any policy<br/> your account will be banned. <a href=\"terms.php\">Review User Policy</a> and<br/>login when ready.</div>";
            echo "<a href=\"#\"><div class=\"infobox-close12\"></div></a>";



    } else { // Form has not been submitted.
        if (isset($_GET['logout']) && $_GET['logout'] == 2) {
            $message = "<div class=\"infobox_out\">Sorry, we've had to log you out. Your session has expired.</div>";
            echo "<a href=\"#\"><div class=\"infobox-close2\"></div></a>";



            } else { // Form has not been submitted.
        if (isset($_GET['logout']) && $_GET['logout'] == 1) {
            $message = "<div class=\"infobox\">You are now logged out.</div>";
            echo "<a href=\"#\"><div class=\"infobox-close3\"></div></a>";

        }

        } 

    }
            }
            }


        $email = "";
        $password = "";
    }
?>






<br/>
            <?php if (!empty($message)) {echo "<p class=\"message\">" . $message . "</p>";} ?>









 <form action="login.php" rel="shadowbox;height=300;width=500" method="post" >

                <div class="row email">
                    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" value="<?php echo htmlentities($email); ?>" />
                </div>

                <div class="row password">
                    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" value="<?php echo htmlentities($email); ?>" />
                </div>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login >"  />
            </form>
            <?php if (!empty($errors)) { display_errors($errors); } ?>
```

Comment: I wouldn't consider `_` to be a special character in any capacity ... where are you checking for email address errors?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I can find you an actual answer, but I can't see you using escape string here, which means your code could be subject to SQL injection. If the problem is something to do with the underscore being a special character, you should do this (you should be doing it anyway, really!)

```
$myescapedstring = escapestring($mystring)
```

You should be doing this for anything which is being passed to your database for querying.

You'd implement it like this:

```
$email = escapestring(trim(mysql_prep($_POST['email'])));
$password = escapestring(trim(mysql_prep($_POST['password'])));
$hashed_password = md5($password);
```

Comment: where bouts do i add that?

Comment: At any point where you are building an SQL statement... I think you could do it here:

        $email = escapestring(trim(mysql_prep($_POST['email'])));
        $password = escapestring(trim(mysql_prep($_POST['password'])));
        $hashed_password = md5($password);